# python global error. It gives me at line 16 of my code. Where search is not defined why?

Tags: python

i have written down the code but it gives me an error. It gives the global error and says that  it does not define the search. Please help me out guys.

```
def testSearch():
  s = range(0,1000000)
  raw_input('basic, -1')
  print search(s,-1)
  raw_input('binary, -1')
  print search1(s,-1)
  raw_input('basic, end')
  print search(s,1000000)
  raw_input('binary, end')
  print search1(s,1000000)
  s = range(0,10000000)
  raw_input('basic, partway')
  print search(s,1000000)
  raw_input('basic, larger end')
  print search(0,10000000)

>>> testSearch()
basic, -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    testSearch()
  File "C:\Users\bangash\Documents\python files\lec8.py", line 17, in testSearch
    print search(s,-1)
NameError: global name 'search' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you defined `search` before the `testSearch`?

Comment: What is your code intended to do?

Comment: I was expecting if it told you something wrong but yes, global name "search" is highly likely not be be defined...

Comment: Maybe you forgot the `1` of `search1` in the last two calls?

Answer (score 0):

So, where is your function `search` defined? You should define it as a function:

```
def search(a, b):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `search` has to be defined before the code in `testSearch` has been executed. The code in `testSearch` is executed when `testSearch()` is executed. So the following two will work

```
def search():
    pass

def testSearch():
    search()

testSearch()
```

or

```
def testSearch():
    search()

def search():
    pass

testSearch()
```

They both will work because, just before the `testSearch()` is executed, we got definition for `search`. But not this

```
def testSearch():
    search()

testSearch()

def search():
    pass
```